# OTServer Canary Protocol 13.21 Retrieve Item classification, tier and imbuements from database, is it possible?

Tags: canary-deployment

I have created a page on `MYACC Gesior` for the users to inspect another character's equipment if set in the character preferences for my Tibia OT Server.

The question is: Is it possible to retrieve the current `item classification` and `tier` data (**forge system**) from the player's equipment from the DB? Is it even stored in the database? And what about the `imbuements` if any applied to the item slots?